# Attribute of relationship in Core Data is returning nil when being called in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an iOS application where I am using Core Data for storage. I have two entities ("MyEntity", and "OtherEntity") which are in a one to one relationship.  Both entities are related to each other (i.e. each entity has an inverse relationship with the other).  In addition to having a relationship with each other, one of the attributes of each entity is also the primarykey of the other entity.

The problem I am having is that I realize that I shouldn't have an attribute that is the foreign key of another entity, when the entities have a relationship with each other, however I am unable to retrieve the primary key indirectly by referencing the relationship attribute, but I am able to retrieve it by referencing the attribute that I explicitly set to the primary key of the other entity:

```
//NSInteger userId = [testUser.otherEntity.userId integerValue]; --> returns nil
  NSInteger userId = [testUser.userId integerValue]; --> works fine
```

where "testUser" is an instance of type "MyEntity" which is a subclass of NSManagedObject, and "otherEntity" is an instance of the Entity, "OtherEntity" that has an inverse relationship with "MyEntity".

Here are the attributes of each Entity:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class OtherEntity;

@interface MyEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * primaryId; //primary key for MyEntity
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * metaData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate * birthDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * userId; //this is the primary key for OtherEntity
@property (nonatomic, strong) OtherEntity *otherEntity;

@end
```

and here are the attributes for OtherEntity:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class MyEntity;

@interface OtherEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * city;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * country;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * fax;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * phone;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * postalCode;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * province;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * myUserId//primary key of MyEntity
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * userId;//primary key of Other Entity
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyEntity *myEntity;

@end
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ca you show mi the attribute of each entity?

Comment: Did you check if `testUser.otherEntity` is nil or not? If not: what is the value of `testUser.otherEntity.userId`?

Comment: I've provided my code that shows the attributes of each entity.  I have data for each entity in my storage for the application, and it's because of this I haven't tested to see if testUser.otherEntity is nil or not.  I guess I will try this out and see what happens.

Comment: If your `testUser.otherEntity` is not nil and `testUser.otherEntity.userId` is not nil check whether `userId` attribute on `otherEntity` is set up as integer.

Comment: @syedfa: Can you show the code where the objects are created and the relationships established? If you don't set a relationship from `testUser` to an OtherEntity object, then `testUser.otherEntity` will be nil.

Comment: @MartinR You identified my error.  I wasn't setting a value for the relationship attribute, which is why it was resulting nil.  Can you post your comment as a solution so that I may select it as an answer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(From the comments:)* You did not set a relationship for `testUser`,
Therefore `testUser.otherEntity` is `nil`.

Then `testUser.otherEntity.userId` is also `nil` and `[testUser.otherEntity.userId integerValue]` return zero.